# Formatting empty lines in eclipse formatter C++/C

Tags: c++, eclipse, formatter

I am playing with my eclipse formatter.

I am currently stuck and cannot format empty new lines.

An example:

```
char string1[5] = "1234";




char string2[5] = "1234";
```

I have 4 new lines that shall be removed when I save the file.
Like this :

```
char string1[5] = "1234";

char string2[5] = "1234";
```

I have now 1 new line per declaration.

I know that I can use CTRL + SHIFT + F.

But I want it to happen automatically when the file is saved.

Here is another example

I tried that but it did not work, however, when I press CTRL + SHIFT + F, the extra empty lines are stripped to one line.

I want this to be an automated process.

Also, I want to choose if I should auto indent it to no empty lines after ex one struct declaration or after a curly brace.

```
static test test1 =
{
    .fi1. = "test",

    .fi2 = "test"
};
function_next
```

```
static test test1 =
{
    .fi1. = "test1",
    .fi2 = "test2"
};

function_next
```

Answer (score 0):

In Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor -> Save Actions There is a "Format source code" check box. If you select that and choose "Format all lines" or "Format edited lines", I believe it will apply your code formatter when saving the file.

Comment: I still get the same behavior

Comment: Well, it was an idea.

Comment: Ah ok.. the java settings and the C++ settings are not equivalent. I found another eclipse plugin called Jindent but it is not for free.